# how to send rich txt using Twilio's autopilot

Tags: video, sms, mms

Hi I'm interested in sending rich media using Twilio's autopilot function. Can anyone suggest a way to do this?
I'm aware that this probably isn't possible currently.
Another fix is to send it over a WhatApps Bot but this is also a little convoluted...I've followed the example however, the image don'ts display. Either way can anyone help me by suggesting other avenues of achieving this? I would ideally like my bot to send picture's and short video over programmable sms/mms